# Selenium won't fetch text fomr webelement (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code in Python/Selenium:

```
try:
   main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main"))
   )
   print(main.text)
except:
   driver.quit()
```

And expecting a print statement but the "try" block seems to fail. I have all the right packages imported and what not but no dice. I am following along with a tutorial and everything has been working fine up to this point. Am happy to post the file thus far if needed. But just wondering why it is failing every pass. Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: So I'm just tryna fetch/print the main content of the page given by:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">...</main> ==$0
```

I have basically zero knowledge of html and I am just trying to follow along with a tutorial so I have no idea why its throwing errors.

Comment: Please include the html element in question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
print(main.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

or

```
print(main.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
```